# Locking windows special key controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm creating stand-alone online exam application for a computer institute, I wanna disable special keys such <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Del</kbd>, winkey etc. So I can protect them from using another applications (browser, etc.) I just want the student can use only this application it can be terminated only if the pressed finish.

```
if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt && e.SystemKey == Key.F4 ||
               Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.SystemKey ==Key.Escape)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
else
{
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
}
```

I tried this code but it works only for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> for winkey its not working i tried that too.

Comment: The word you're looking for is "kiosk mode"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can force the machine to run windows 8.1, you can simply create a user that only has access to your application.

This feature is called Assigned Access.  You can even automate a lot of the setup using a [powershell script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449310%28v=winembedded.82%29.aspx).

[Here](https://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/10/28/how-to-setup-assigned-access-in-windows-8-1-kiosk-mode.aspx) is a decent article to get you started on how to set it up manually.

Comment: but they are using windows server 2008 network monitor

Answer (score 0):

You could always handle it with the registry, I've heard (and I don't know if it has any validity to it) but modifying the *DisableTaskMgr* key (setting it to '1' I believe).

I did find this: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/1021/how-to-disable-ctrlaltdel/
Which is possible to do it in VB6. Look into PInvoke in user32.dll